# Include `meta` member in resource identifiers in `relationships` object

Tags: active-model-serializers, json-api

From my understanding of the JSON:API spec (specifically https://jsonapi.org/format/#document-resource-object-linkage) I should be able to include `meta` members for each member of a relationship.

I have been able to add a hash of `meta` data to the `relationships` object itself, but not one to each of the individual relationships within.

```rb
class PlanSerializer < ApplicationSerializer
  attributes :id, :name

  has_many :features do
    meta value: "x"
  end
end
```

I know I can use a block syntax for `has_many`, and think that's the way to achieve this. But I haven't got it working. Calling the `meta` method within the block adds the meta block to the `features` relationship object, and I need to add one to each entry in that array.

My questions:

**Have I understood the spec correctly? *Should* I be able to add a `meta` object to each relationship?**

**How would I go about doing this with the active model serializers?**

Background:
My goal is to represent a many-many from Plans to Features where each plan might have some extra information for it's own relationship to a given Feature (and that information is different for every Plan, so it doesn't belong on the Feature object)

If your answer is that I *shouldn't* be doing this, that's fine, but please present an alternative which you think is preferred.

```
// My desired output
{
  "data": [
    {
      "id": "small",
      "type": "plans",
      "attributes": {
        /* Some attributes */      
      },
      "relationships": {
        "features": {
          "data": [
            {
              "id": "num-users",
              "type": "features",
              "meta": {
                "value": 1
              }
            },
            {
              "id": "num-projects",
              "type": "features",
              "meta": {
                "value": 5
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "id": "large",
      "type": "plans",
      "attributes": {
        /* Some attributes */
      },
      "relationships": {
        "features": {
          "data": [
            {
              "id": "num-users",
              "type": "features",
              "meta": {
                "value": 5
              }
            },
            {
              "id": "num-projects",
              "type": "features",
              "meta": {
                "value": 50
              }
            },
            {
              "id": "unlimited-downloads",
              "type": "features"
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  ],
  "included": [
    {
      "id": "num-users",
      "type": "features",
      "attributes": {
        "description": "Number of users"
      }
    },
    {
      "id": "num-projects",
      "type": "features",
      "attributes": {
        "description": "Number of projects"
      }
    },
    {
      "id": "unlimited-downloads",
      "type": "features",
      "attributes": {
        "description": "Unlimited downloads"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: What you are trying to achieve looks fine from spec perspective. But I'm not sure if it's supported by Rails `ActiveModel::Serializers`.

Comment: Thanks, @jelhan. I've changed approach for now for this reason, I still this it's okay by the spec but wasn't been able to make it work with `ActiveModel::Serializers`.